# How to do Update , Delete process using Code First Approach?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one big doubt. I have "Customer Form". Customer Form contain 22 fields. I have Db for "Customer Form". it Contain"Multiple tables" with "many to many relationship". If I connect my Db with "Vb express 2012" using "Connection Strings"  and also created **EDMX** file.it shows view for each table. so i tried to bring all fields in "Single view" and tried to insert the data into multiple tables. For that I used "**Code First Approach**" i followed the method same as like which is mentioned in the below link. Its working Fine.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/651495/Inserting-Data-into-Multiple-Tables-using-Code-Fir

Now my question is i finished the "insert" process using Code first approach.. Now " how to do UPDATE process using this approach.. Because i did only the insertion process . still i need to do Update , Details, Delete.. How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you plz elaborate more? I understand that you want to edit and delete the data from database.. am I right?

Comment: yes you exactly right Awais .My question  is "How to do Update, Delete Process using Code First Approach". I complete Insert process using code first approach same as like mentioned in the below link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/651495/Inserting-Data-into-Multiple-Tables-using-Code-Fir 

so I need to do Update and delete process in MVC4. My Customer form is complete up to insert process. Still i need to do update and delete process .. How to do that using Code first approach .This is my doubt?

Answer (score 1):

add your customers in a foreach lop in a view and pass each ones primary key to the edit and delete methods of the controller as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.s1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.s2)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

then in your controller make a GET method to accept the primary key as a parameter from the view as follows:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Class1 class1 = db.Class1.Find(id);
    return View(class1);
}
```

and then make a Form in your Edit View to POST back the values as:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Class1</h4>
        <hr />

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.s1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.s1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.s2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.s2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

then in your controller make a POST method to accept the model as a parameter from the view as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,s1,s2")] Class1 class1)
{           
    db.Entry(class1).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Similarly make GET and POST methods for Delete.

Answer (score 0):

basically in an update method...

1. Find the object to be updated
   -Example your datacontext class object=ctx,tablename=details
2. update the found object with the new data

if you're not passing an entire object to the method then just pass the primary key of the object to be updated and the new values

```
  public void update(details newData)
{
var result=ctx.details.Find(id);
result.name=newData.Name;
result.age=newData.Age;
ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

to Delete:
a similar process

1. Find the object -Example your datacontext class object=ctx,tablename=details
2. Remove it

> 

```
  public void Delete(int id)
    {
    var result=ctx.details.Find(id);
    ctx.details.Remove(result);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```